# How to get data from database in array format using node js and MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, vuejs2

I am using node.js as server language and Mysql as database so I am running query and getting data from database but is is showing in format like this

```
  [ BinaryRow { name: 'Dheeraj', amount: '77.0000' },
    BinaryRow { name: 'Raju', amount: '255.0000' } ]
```

What I want is

```
    ['Dheeraj', 77.0000],
    ['Raju', 66255.000030],
```

This what I am doing in my backend (node.js):

My model:

```
static getChartData(phoneNo, userType) {

        let sql = 'select businessname as name,sum(billamt) amount from cashbackdispdets where consphoneno =' + phoneNo + ' group by  businessid order by tstime desc limit 10'
        return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo]);
```

My controller:

```
exports.getColumnChart = function(req, res) {
    const phoneNo = req.body.userId
    const userType = req.body.userType
    console.log(phoneNo)
    dashboardModule.getChartData(phoneNo, userType)
        .then(([rows]) => {
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                console.log(rows)
                return res.json(rows)
            } else {
                console.log("error")
                return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Phone No. already taken' })
            }
        })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Something went wrong !!' })
    })
}
```

I am sending this data to `Ui` and when I am receiving it on `UI`  it is in the form of object inside array which is not the required data type I want

```
axios().post('/api/v1/Dashboard/DashboardColumnChart',this.form)
  .then(res=>{
    console.log(res.data)
    debugger
  this.chartData= res.data
       })
```

The above code consoles on browser like [image: this]

I am not getting any idea how o do it should I do it with backend or with front end and how

Comment: Use an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) library called [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) for this purpose. It will make querying and receiving data much simpler.

Comment: @HussainNawazLalee can you help me with a little example please

Comment: You will have to add some boilerplate, so if you are already a long way into the project I would not recommend it but if you are just beginning you can start using this library. After you have set up sequelize in your project. Let's say you want to `SELECT * FROM Products`. Sequelize will have `Product` model defined and you can just call `Product.findAll()` and it will return all the products in JSON format. You also have helpful methods like `incldue` to get `related Tables as nested objects` and many other stuff that makes it easy to work with Node

Comment: As for the current use case I have added an answer that will help you format the data

Comment: Your code is also currently vulnerable to SQL injection, so I really recommend revisiting the way you are constructing your query, should this be used in prod.

Comment: @huhnmonster that was mistake now I am using `?` to pass values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs will send you a JSON response if you want to change it. It is better to change or maniuplate it in a Front end framework. But if you want to change it in backend as you have asked Make sure that the rows is in the format that you want to recive.

```
 let data = [ 
        { "name": "Dheeraj", "amount": "77.0000" }, 
        { "name": "Raju", "amount": "255.0000" } 
    ]
    // empty array to store the data
    let testData = [];
    data.forEach(element => {
          testData.push(element.name)
    });
```

Comment: On Ui I don't have any idea how to do it(manipulation) and in backend it is coming as in object in array format

Comment: what are you using for fronend of this application. It is normal , Node js will send the response as JSON object. If you want to send in that sepecific format. use `return res(rows)`. It will fix your problem then it will not be an object of JSON type. It will be plain response

Comment: `vuejs` I am using and from node i is send plain responce the it will be in form [{}] this only I want to send it like [][] this in array form above in my post I have showed, and how can I do it with front end not getting any idea

Comment: I am getting responce like this `[ { "name": "Dheeraj", "amount": "77.0000" }, { "name": "Raju", "amount": "255.0000" } ]` but i want   `['Dheeraj', 77.0000],
    ['Raju', 66255.000030],` this

Comment: Dear friend let me solve your question in your front end app or backend you can apply the following code . data is the response coming from the server. now we will manuplate. Check the answer I updated it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it using `array.map` and `Object.values`. `map` functions loops over each element and returns a modified element according to the callback provided. `Object.values` simply returns all the values of an object in an array.

```js
const data = [ { "name": "Dheeraj", "amount": "77.0000" }, { "name": "Raju", "amount": "255.0000" } ];

const formattedData = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj));

console.log("Initial Data: ", data);
console.log("Formatted Data: ", formattedData);


// Map function example
const a = [1,2,3]
const mappedA = a.map(e => e * 2)
console.log(a, " mapped to: ", mappedA);

// Object.values example
const b = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', number: '120120' }
console.log(Object.values(b));
```

Comment: You can use `parseInt(string)` to convert your `string` to a `number`